# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping must specify either a <url-pattern> or a <servlet-name>

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters, resteasy

I've created very simple REST app with next web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm using servlet 3.0 specification and Tomcat 7.0.23. Unfortunately it fails all time:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping must specify either a <url-pattern> or a <servlet-name>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2995)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2954)
```

I don't imagine where problem is... I don't use filters in my code, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is related to [RESTEasy issue 577](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-577). To fix this, you need to add `metadata-complete="true"` to the `<web-app>` root declaration of your `/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

```xml
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

This way Tomcat will assume that the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` is complete and won't scan JARs for additional metadata information in `web.xml` fragments which in case of RESTEasy apparently contain incorrectly/incompletely declared filters.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, adding 'metadata-complete="true"' will block any other jars from contributing to web.xml, including RichFaces and Seam. It is better to exclude the offending JAR file from your deployment. In my case, it was the async-http-servlet-3.0-2.3.3.Final.jar who offended.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Tomcat 7 (version < 7.0.28), see [that reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10873185/535203) to a similar question, and the [linked Tomcat 7 bugzilla ticket](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53354).