# Scanning rest resources in application with existing servlets

Tags: jsp, rest, servlets, resteasy

I am having an application which is having both Rest resources and custom servlets, with the configuration given below. Following it, rest resources are reachable, but the servlet is not reachable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name></display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/abc/api/*</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.Servlet1</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1<servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What's the functional requirement? With the configuration posted so far, all requests on `/abc/api/*` will invoke the Rest resources, but **not** the servlet. Only requests on `/abc/*` which do *not* match `/abc/api/*` should invoke the servlet.

Comment: Yes, the underlying requirement is exactly the same ass you elaborated, but it is somehow not working.

Comment: Which servletcontainer are you using?

Comment: I tested with your web.xml file, I could not start the Tomcat 7 server, I got a servlet-mapping error, Look at this @Balusc answer related to some other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581770/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-filter-mapping-must-specify-either-a-url-pa, I am little confused since you are saying that rest easy is working, since i could not start the server at all

Answer (score 0):

I tested with a simple app and this following config works as far as servlet is concerned. The only change **between your web.xml and mine is metadata-complete=true**, I did not test the rest part though only servlet part

http://serverurl/contextRoot/abc/Servlet1 (this works)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
     <display-name></display-name>
       <context-param>
             <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
             <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>
       <context-param>
           <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
           <param-value>/abc/api/*</param-value>
        </context-param>
  <listener>
   <display-name>Rest Easy JBOSS</display-name>
   <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
       <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
       <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>prasanna.servlets.PrintEnvServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
   </web-app>
```

My Servelt class

```
    public class PrintEnvServlet extends HttpServlet 
    {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 4765435575183820979L;

   protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest req,     javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse resp) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException
    {
     java.util.Map<String,String> mapOfEnv = System.getenv();
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for(String key : mapOfEnv.keySet())
     {
        builder.append(key);
        builder.append(":");
        builder.append(mapOfEnv.get(key));
        builder.append("\n\n");
     }
     resp.getWriter().write(builder.toString());
    }

 }
```