# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name <filtername

Tags: servlets, mapping, servlet-filters, illegalargumentexception

I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name MyFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3139)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1362)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more
```

The filter is present in a jar file which is part of the delivered war.

```
@WebFilter(filterName="MyFilter",
        urlPatterns = {"/page/*"})
public class myFilter implements Filter {
```

Can anybody tell me what i have to do that the filter can be found?

it is not a duplicate of the question [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [X] and [Y] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/url] which is not permitted](http://java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:%20The%20servlets%20named%20[X]%20and%20[Y]%20are%20both%20mapped%20to%20the%20url-pattern%20[/url]%20which%20is%20not%20permitted) because it is a very different error message

Comment: @BalusC Yes i have the metadata-complete Attribute. Tomcat Version is  Apache Tomcat/7.0.68

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named \[X\] and \[Y\] are both mapped to the url-pattern \[/url\] which is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270619/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-servlets-named-x-and-y-are-both-mapp)

Comment: @Anonymous Why this should be a dupplicate. Everything is different also the error message. BTW. Thanks for downvoting

Comment: @Downvoter: Thanks for downvoting one ore time without Explanation. It is very helpfull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other words, the `@WebFilter` is not recognized. This can happen when you have a `metadata-complete="true"` attribute in `<web-app>` element of `web.xml`. It basically means that the container assumes that the `web.xml` itself is complete as to metadata and thus it won't scan for metadata (annotations) in JARs shipped in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

You have several options.

1. Set `metadata-complete="false"`.
2. Remove `metadata-complete` altogether. The default value is already `false`.
3. Explicitly register the filter via `<filter>`.

Another probable cause is a bug in Tomcat which is already fixed in 7.0.28. See also this related question: [Using Tomcat, @WebFilter doesn't work with <filter-mapping> inside web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10856866).